# User is aggressively requesting deleting my answer so they can delete their question

Tags: discussion

OP keeps editing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893165/what-is-meant-by-this-useless), making it "post for test purposes", and keeps asking me to delete my answer so they can delete their question because it was downvoted.

OP's also [editing my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24602601) and is downvoting my answers.

I tried dropping a comment explaining why downvotes aren't necessarily, but OP "threatened" they will delete the current account and create a new "clean" one.

I'm not worried about the downvotes he's giving to my posts, I'm more worried about users who're not satisfied with downvotes, and will eventually create another "clean" account.

How should we deal with this?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a trivial duplicate for such basic question then it can be deleted by the community

Comment: @TemaniAfif two, as it's asking about two operators: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434465/what-does-a-pipe-character-do-in-a-shell-bash-command

Comment: Ignore the pressure; flag for moderator attention. This has been handled. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Guys, I know that it can be closed as a duplicate, I'm asking for a way to handle such scenarios in general.

Comment: And now people are voting to delete the question, so OP will get his wish after all, due to this meta-question.

Comment: *"OP's also editing my answer "* ... looks more like OP is "rolling back" your answer into the first revision of your answer. But why you wrote "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..." as an answer is beyond me.

Comment: @Tom I first thought I misunderstood the question, then I realized I actually got it right.

Comment: This [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58893266/1) really looks weird. It looks like you anticipated the post being closed, and wanted to have a deleted answer to circumvent closure. If that was the case, very lame.

Comment: @yivi Again, I first thought I misunderstood the question, then I realized that it was correct, and reverted it back.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm probably having an off-day, but I don't get it. How misunderstanding the question in any way makes "xxxxxxx" a reasonable answer? That was the first ever revision. You mean you posted an answer, then vandalized it before the grace period, and only then deleted it? Sorry if it's otherwise obvious, but without context it does look weird.

Comment: @yivi I wrote an answer, then deleted it along with the content before the grace period, then realized that I got the question right (`&` confused with `&&`).

Comment: What I don't get with that is, why you "vandalized" your own answer? As you know, deleted post is only visible to 10k rep users, so to very few people and there is no harm in having a wrong answer deleted (and still visible to those few people), but doesn't that look "better" than having a "xxxxxxxxxx" answer deleted with no visible edit due to the grace period? That also avoids confusion when you un-delete your answer. What I prefer to do in such case is just to add a comment under my answer, saying it is wrong and then delete my answer. If it was right, then I can just delete the comment.

Comment: @Tom You're right, I wasn't supposed to do that, it's not better than leaving a deleted answer with its wrong content.

Answer (score 20):

Flag one of the posts of the OP for moderator attention and explain the situation. Also, attach the [Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24602601) done by the OP to attract downvotes on a valid answer, and it will be handled by them.

Comment: My message exceeded the 200 characters, which turns out to be the limit for messages to mods ;)

Comment: Good to know it isn't just me who regularly exceeds the character limit for textboxes on this site, @Maroun. It isn't necessary to link to the actual suggested edit. We can find that information easily, as long as you point us to the right post. If it's really necessary to share more information, you can link to a Gist or something like https://privatebin.net/. Or you can ping one of us in chat (we can even create private rooms for moderation purposes, if you want to share sensitive information). But, in general, most of us are pretty good at figuring out the problem with just a quick summary.

Comment: @Maroun 200 chars is the limit for comments flag messages, do you really intend to flag comment? Post flag messages have much higher limit of 500 chars, I just checked

Comment: Ah yeah, gnat implicitly raises a good point. *Please* flag posts for complex situations like this, not comments. Comment flags can only be disposed of two ways: by deleting or not deleting the comment. You should use them accordingly, to request deletion of a comment. Not to send moderators a message. @maroun